# update query to update table based on a record from same table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a small issue with a query to update a record in a table based on a record from the same table. Below are the details.

**Cust_Master**

```
Cust_ID - Reference_ID - Bal_Amount
----------
C100001 - R12345       - 30
C100002 - R12346       - 0
C100003 - R12345       - 0
C100004 - R12347       - 20
C100005 - R12345       - 0
```

What I need is to update the `Bal_Amount where Reference_ID = Reference_ID of Cust_ID (C100001)`, but should not update Cust_ID (C100001), that means source record should not get updated.

Finally the values should be C100003 and C100005 should get the Bal_Amount as 30.

I tried with the below query which is not working as required.

```
update Minbo_DB.dbo.Cust_Master 
set Cust_Master.Bal_Amount = Cust_Master2.Bal_Amount 
from Cust_Master 
inner join Cust_Master Cust_Master2 
     ON Cust_Master2.Reference_ID = (select Reference_ID 
                                     from Cust_Master 
                                     where Cust_ID='C100001') 
     AND Cust_Master.Cust_ID <> 'C100001'
where 
    (Cust_Master.Cust_ID <> 'C100001')
```

Comment: Any Comments here is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not entirely clear, so here an approach we can work from can refine...

```
CREATE TABLE #Example
(
    Cust_ID         VARCHAR(25),
    Reference_ID    VARCHAR(25), 
    Bal_Amount      INT
)
INSERT INTO #Example
    SELECT 'C100001', 'R12345', 30   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C100002', 'R12346', 0    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C100003', 'R12345', 0    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C100004', 'R12347', 20   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C100005', 'R12345', 0


;WITH Aggregation AS
(
    SELECT Reference_ID, BalMax =  MAX(Bal_Amount)
    FROM #Example
    GROUP BY Reference_ID
)
UPDATE  E
SET Bal_Amount = BalMax
FROM Aggregation    A
JOIN #Example       E   ON A.Reference_ID = E.Reference_ID
WHERE Bal_Amount != BalMax


SELECT *
FROM #Example
```

Comment: Hi Mark, My requirement is to update Bal_Amt of all the records with the same reference ID as C100001 except C100001.

Answer (score 0):

Hi All i have got the solution. Below is the answer for it.

update Cust_Master set Cust_Jars_Bal = Cust_Master2.Cust_Jars_Bal 
from Cust_Master inner join Cust_Master Cust_Master2 ON Cust_Master.Reference_ID = Cust_Master2.Reference_ID
where (Cust_Master2.Cust_ID = 'C100001').

Thank you for your Contributions...